# golang os.Getenv always return with a prefix of git dir in Windows git bash

Tags: windows, go, git-bash

when I use `os.Getenv` in windows git bash, if env's value starts with '/', I will get a result which starts with 'C:/Program Files/Git', I don't know why and how to fix it.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

go code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv(`TEST123`))
}
```

output in Windows git bash:
[image]

golang version: 1.18
git version: 2.41.0.windows.1

Comment: I'm not on Windows so just taking a guess here but does it work if you try `export TEST123='/1'`. i.e. wrap the value with quotes

Comment: @mkopriva `echo` is correct, `echo $TEST123` output is `/1`

Comment: @Aditya, tried and got a same result: `export TEST123='/1'` and then `go run main.go` , output `C:/Program Files/Git/1`. And `export TEST123="/1"` got a same result

Comment: @mkdym it appears to be a known issue of windows git-bash: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/discussions/3038

Comment: Windows shells seem notoriously bad for these string parsing errors. I believe `echo` might act differently as a shell builtin vs a real application